# Symfony 6 - How to bulk update data

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms, bulkupdate, symfony6

I want to make a single form to bulk edit data. Let's say I want to edit some value/s of a variable amount of users and save it all at the same time.

[image: example of what i want to do]

I can create a form with `php bin/console make:form` but it allow me to edit just one entry. I am looking for the "oficial way" to do id but I don't find any clear information.

What would be the most correct way to do this in Symfony 6?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The simpler way would be to make a CollectionType with a custom entry type for your users and values

Comment: I am reading about CollectionType and have no clue how to do it at the moment. Can you give an example. I keep researching